# What are the difference between _from, _spender and _to address in Ethereum in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

What are the difference between _from, _spender and _to address in these functions below?

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public{/*...*/}
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public{/*...*/}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the functions used in an ERC20 token contract.

- `_from` : original owner of tokens who can himself transfer some tokens or approve any third party/person to spend the token
- `_spender` : Spender who can transfer tokens on the behalf of    someone    only if approved by token owner
- `_to` : Address who will    receive the    tokens in any case.

You can visit it the complete contract [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol) . Comments are quite self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

From the [ERC20 specification](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md#transferfrom):

> **transferFrom**
>
> Transfers `_value` amount of tokens from address `_from` to address
>   `_to`, and MUST fire the `Transfer` event.
>
> The `transferFrom` method is used for a withdraw workflow, allowing
>   contracts to transfer tokens on your behalf. This can be used for
>   example to allow a contract to transfer tokens on your behalf and/or
>   to charge fees in sub-currencies. The function SHOULD `throw` unless
>   the `_from` account has deliberately authorized the sender of the
>   message via some mechanism.

> **approve**
>
> Allows `_spender` to withdraw from your account multiple times, up to
>   the `_value` amount. If this function is called again it overwrites
>   the current allowance with `_value`.

Basically, you can use `approve` to allow someone else to spend/withdraw tokens from your balance. The `transferFrom` method is the function that is called by that person to actually spend tokens from your account.